# React-router-dom : Is it possible to use Link without routing the user to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this table:

```
<Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nom du fichier</th>
                  <th>Date et heure d'ajout</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.fichierJointsInformation.map(
                  (operationSavInformation, i) => {
                    return (
                      <tr key={i}>
                        <td>
                          <Link
                            to={""}
                            onClick={this.onFichierJointLinkClicked}
                          >
                            {operationSavInformation.nomFichierOriginal}
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>{operationSavInformation.createdAt}</td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  }
                )}
              </tbody>
            </Table>
```

It is rendered like this:
[image]

**What I am trying to implement:** When the user clicks on any element of the first column, the associated file gets downloaded.
So the `onFichierJointLinkClicked` onClick listener, will take care of the API request and everything else.

```
<Link
                        to={""}
                        onClick={this.onFichierJointLinkClicked}
                      >
                        {operationSavInformation.nomFichierOriginal}
                      </Link>
```

**MY PROBLEM:** The `to` prop in *LINK* is required. However, I don't want to route the user to any other page. I just want the `onFichierJointLinkClicked` to be triggered.

If I remove the `to` prop, I get this error obviously:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Comment: Why can't you use a normal `<button>` and style it to look like a link?

Comment: @apokryfos didn't think of that cuz a button well, it's a button not a link.

Comment: Also, the links in my app have a particular appearance and I need them all to look the same even if this one won't redirect to another page

Comment: The problem here is that a `<Link>` component is not any old link but a react router link which has a specific purpose. What you're describing can be an anchor link with the download attribute (e.g. `<a href=X download>...</a>`) or can be a callback triggered by clicking a button.  The only issue is visual so you will need to find a way to apply the same styling to the `<Link>` as well as your download link/button.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the detailed response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to put `#` i.e. `to="#"`,  as I am doing. And it is working fine for me -

Please see -

```
<div className="pagination alternate pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li className={props.prevPage == null ? 'disabled' : ''}>
      <NavLink
        to="#"
        onClick={() => props.gotoPage(props.prevPage, props.noOfPages)}
      >
        Prev
      </NavLink>
    </li>
    {links}
    <li className={props.nextPage == null ? 'disabled' : ''}>
      <NavLink
        to="#"
        onClick={() => props.gotoPage(props.nextPage, props.noOfPages)}
      >
        Next
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems, you no longer need a Link, set a style for your td element to behave like a link, and attach the onClick event listener

i tried to reproduce a bit your need here

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import "./styles.css";



export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nom du fichier</th>
                  <th>Date et heure d'ajout</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td className="likeALink" onClick={() => console.log("your custom function")}>
                        something
                    </td>
                    <td>something else</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.likeALink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.likeALink {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Link with a custom div, then style it with a little bit of css (cursor: pointer, color, :hover:...)

Then in your onFichierJointLinkClicked, open your pdf in another window like this:

```
window.open(path, '_blank');
```